# How do mouse-events work in chrome? (d3-V4)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I just tested my site, which I developed with Edge-browser, in Chrome.
There, some of the mouse-events are not triggerd.

Is it possible, that mouseover, mousedown etc. do not work this way with Chrome?

```
for (var i = 0; i < graphics.length; i++) {
    var graphic = graphics[i];
    const graph = svgEditor.append("g")
        .attr("id", graphic.Id.toString())
        .attr("pointer-events", "fill")
        .on("mousedown", mousedownGraphic)   
        .on("mouseup", mouseupGraphic)
        .on("mouseover", mouseoverGraphic)
        .on("mouseout", mouseoutGraphic)
        .call(d3.drag()
            .on("start", dragGraphicStart)
            .on("drag", dragGraphic)
            .on("end", dragGraphicStop));
    graph.html(graphic.SvgString).on("mouseover", mouseoverGraphic);
    //moseover, mouseout
}
```

This is the way, I create my svg-graphic, which works fine with Edge.

Comment: Funny that this Question is voted down. It would have been better if I get an answer or a Suggestion, how to solve this Problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So guys,
I think I have a solution for this behaviour.

On svg-lines, Chrome seems to have a Problem with

```
.attr("pointer-events", "fill")
```

So I have to select wether I only have a line or other, more complex stuff.
Thanks for watching :)